# How to exclude commons-logging from a scala/sbt/slf4j project?

Tags: scala, sbt, slf4j

My scala/sbt project uses grizzled-slf4j and logback. A third-party dependency uses Apache Commons Logging.

With Java/Maven, I would use jcl-over-slf4j and logback-classic so that I can use logback as the unified logging backend.

I would also eliminate the commons-logging dependency that the third-party lib would let sbt pull in. I do the following in Maven (which is recommended by http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And the question is, how to do the same with sbt?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Heiko's approach will probably work, but will lead to none of the dependencies of the 3rd party lib to be downloaded. If you only want to exclude a specific one use `exclude`.

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" % "bar" % "0.7.0" exclude("org.baz", "bam")
```

or

```
... excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization = "org.baz") ) // does not work with generated poms!
```

Comment: It works. And my final solution is `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...).map(_.exclude("commons-logging", "commons-logging"))`

Comment: The documentation for this is here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management#exclude-transitive-dependencies

Comment: Update: Recent versions of sbt (since 0.13?) supports "provided", too. I can just write `"commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.2" % "provided"`

Answer (score 28):

For sbt 0.13.8 and above, you can also try the project-level dependency exclusion:

```scala
excludeDependencies += "commons-logging" % "commons-logging"
```

Answer (score 7):

I met the same problem before. Solved it by adding dependency like

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" % "bar" % "0.7.0" exclude("commons-logging","commons-logging")
```

or

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" % "bar" % "0.7.0" excludeAll(ExclusionRule(organization = "commons-logging"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Add *intransitive* your 3rd party library dependency, e.g.

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" %% "bar" % "1.2.3" intransitive
```

Comment: Downvoted, cause can lead to the problems when you have more than one 3rd party dependencies, as drexin noted, sorry.

Comment: This solution actually worked for me (removed all the 3rd party dependencies for 1 explicit dependency).